# Rubik's cube solver in C: program gets killed trying to generate a database

Tags: c, rubiks-cube

I'm trying to implement Korf's algorithm to generate all Rubik's cube corners permutations. In total it must be `8! * 3^7`(88,179,840), but the program gets Killed after generating around (36,000,000) permutations. I used Lehmer code indexing for the permutations and created a table of size (88,179,840) knowing that the index would never surpass that value. `uint32_t *table = (uint32_t *)calloc(88179840, sizeof(uint32_t));`. I checked the result of the indexing function and it gives the right result... for example the permutation (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7) it gives 0 and in (7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0) it gives 40319.
I made a BFS function to expand nodes and get all the permutations and index them. then store them in a file.

```
    void bfs(t_state *top, t_state *tail)
{
    uint32_t i, childCost;
    uint32_t permIndex;
    t_state *curr;
    t_cube new_cube;
    uint32_t *onesCount;
    uint32_t *table = (uint32_t *)calloc(88179840, sizeof(uint32_t));
    FILE *fp;

    fp = fopen("./perms.txt", "w+");
    onesCount = table_of_ones();
    permIndex = get_corner_index(top->cube, onesCount, fp);
    fprintf(fp, "%d|%d \n", permIndex, 0);
    table[permIndex] = 1;
    while (top)
    {
        curr = pop(&top);
        childCost = curr->cost + 1;
        i = 1;
        while (i < 19)
        {
            new_cube = apply_move(curr->cube, i, "");
            permIndex = get_corner_index(new_cube, onesCount, fp);
            if (table[permIndex] == 0)
            {
                table[permIndex] = 1;
                fprintf(fp, "%d|%d\n", permIndex, childCost);
                tail = push(tail, new_cube, childCost);
                if (top == NULL)
                    top = tail;
            }
            i++;
        }
        free(curr);
    }
    fclose(fp);
    free(onesCount);
}
```

[image: i used htop to keep track of memory, and this is a screenshot of the memory sec bfr it got killed]

photo of the program when it gets killed
[image]

Comment: My first idea here is that you are running out of RAM space when your program gets killed -please run it again and monitor your RAM usage.

Comment: Just the table alone should not fill up your RAM - it is only 336 MegaBytes big. But the other functions in your while loop might eat additional RAM …

Comment: What do you mean by "gets killed"?  Is it segfaulting, or getting OOMed, or something else?

Comment: i edited the question to show a screenshot

Comment: WIthout the rest of your code this will be difficult to investigate. You could be leaking memory in any one of your calls. Try running valgrind's memcheck to help you debug this https://valgrind.org/docs/manual/quick-start.html

Comment: Also run your program directly (not through `time`) to get more obvious feedback instead of "Killed"

Comment: i wouldn't mind adding more code.. i just was afraid from bad reviews bc of putting long code. ill try with valgrind.. thank you for your answers.

Comment: Maybe not related, but why is your swap completely full?  Huge files in `/tmp`?

Comment: Also try `/usr/bin/time -v ./a.out` to get memory statistics as well as time.

Comment: You could run the program under pidstat to show memory usage over time: `pidstat -r 1 -e ./a.out`

Comment: Or as above, but `./a.out > test & pidstat -r -p $! 1` to redirect the standard output of ./a.out to a file while monitoring its memory usage.

Comment: Eliminate the simple suspect: After `uint32_t *table = calloc(...)`, test if `table == NULL`.

Comment: Test allocation of `onesCount = table_of_ones();` too.

Comment: Cursious, why no `free(table)`? If calling `bfs()` multiple times, sure to OOM.

Comment: Watching htop won't help if the memory raises quickly. Instead, look at the OOM log (details is specific to distribution)